# Adding a default value to google-places-auto-complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ref, google-places-autocomplete

I'm trying to use the city of a user as a default value to google-places-auto-complete input.

I've tried to use cityAutoComplete?.setAddressText(city) outside of the ref prop but it won't work, and I've tried using it inside of the Ref prop and then it works but won't let me type anything else into that input (in order to change city for exmple).

here's the code which lets me put a default value but won't let me type into the input.

```
  <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                            ref={(ref) => {
                                cityAutoComplete = ref
                                cityAutoComplete?.setAddressText(city)
                            }}
                            styles={{
                                textInputContainer: { height: scale(50) },
                                container: {
                                    width: "100%",
                                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                                },
                                textInput: {
                                    borderBottomWidth: 1,
                                    marginTop: scale(10),
                                    textAlign: "center",
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    fontFamily: "Heebo-Regular",
                                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                                    paddingBottom: 4,
                                    width: scale(200),
                                },
                            }}
                            placeholder={strings("City")}
                            value={city}
                            onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                                setCity(data.terms[0].value);
                                setNeedReload(true);
                            }}
                            query={{
                                types: "(cities)",
                                key: globals.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
                                language: "he",
                            }}
                        />
```